# WPF TextBox with background color and path (image)

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I've got the below style for TextBoxes in my WPF app:

```
<!-- http://www.thexamlproject.com/ -->
<Style x:Key="LockIcon" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
    <Setter Property="Data" 
            Value="F1 M 80.6667,55.1172L 80.6667,35.3333C 80.6667,15.851 64.815,3.05176e-005 45.3333,3.05176e-005C 25.8509,3.05176e-005 9.99998,15.851 9.99998,35.3333L 9.99998,55.1172L 0,56L 0,129.333L 45.3333,133.333L 90.6667,129.333L 90.6667,56L 80.6667,55.1172 Z M 20.6667,54.1771L 20.6667,35.3333C 20.6667,21.7318 31.7317,10.6667 45.3333,10.6667C 58.9349,10.6667 70,21.7318 70,35.3333L 70,54.1771L 45.3333,52L 20.6667,54.1771 Z " />
</Style>

<VisualBrush x:Key="LockBrush" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Border BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="Transparent">
            <Path Style="{StaticResource LockIcon}" Fill="Red" />
        </Border>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LockBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="22,4"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I can't seem to find a good way to apply this VisualBrush image AND a background color to the entire TextBox. I either get strange stretching issues or simply cannot fill the whole TextBox (controls stretch and are different widths depending on the rendering view).

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a VisualBrush use a Control Template.

**XAML**

```
<Style x:Key="LockIcon"
           TargetType="Path">
      <Setter Property="Height"
              Value="16" />
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="16" />
      <Setter Property="Stretch"
              Value="Uniform" />
      <Setter Property="Data"
              Value="F1 M 80.6667,55.1172L 80.6667,35.3333C 80.6667,15.851 64.815,3.05176e-005 45.3333,3.05176e-005C 25.8509,3.05176e-005 9.99998,15.851 9.99998,35.3333L 9.99998,55.1172L 0,56L 0,129.333L 45.3333,133.333L 90.6667,129.333L 90.6667,56L 80.6667,55.1172 Z M 20.6667,54.1771L 20.6667,35.3333C 20.6667,21.7318 31.7317,10.6667 45.3333,10.6667C 58.9349,10.6667 70,21.7318 70,35.3333L 70,54.1771L 45.3333,52L 20.6667,54.1771 Z " />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType='TextBox'
           x:Key='WithLockIcon'>
      <Setter Property='MinHeight'
              Value='26' />
      <Setter Property="Padding"
              Value="22,4" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                 Value="false">
          <!-- Use a control template instead of 
               Background property -->
          <!--<Setter Property="Background"
                  Value="{StaticResource LockBrush}" />-->
          <!--<Setter Property="Padding"
                  Value="22,4" />-->

          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <!-- Set background here!-->
                <Border BorderThickness="4"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        HorizontalAlignment='Stretch'>
                  <StackPanel Background='#dddddd'
                              Orientation='Horizontal'>
                    <Path Style="{StaticResource LockIcon}"
                          Fill="Red" />
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                                  x:Name="PART_ContentHost">

                    </ScrollViewer>

                  </StackPanel>
                </Border>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Trigger>

      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name='textbox1'
             Text='Example Text'
             IsEnabled='False'
             Style='{StaticResource WithLockIcon}' />
    <ToggleButton Checked='ToggleButton_Checked'
                  Unchecked='ToggleButton_Unchecked'
                  Content='Change State' />
  </StackPanel>
```

Comment: This pretty much does the trick, but I was hoping for a solution that would not force me to override the template and lose the other behaviors already set in the control (e.g. fading the text in the disabled TextBox). I would also like to apply the lock icon to behavior grid cells, ComboBoxes, etc. and not have Template overrides for everything. Templates are simple for TextBoxes, not so much for ComboBoxes.

Comment: You can copy all the textbox style and use it in yours.  It looks ugly but it's done quite often. Another option is to create a custom composite control.

Comment: Okay, I give up. It saddens me that overriding the entire template is what I'm forced to do, but this is indeed the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved a reasonably close simulation in a similar situation.

```
<Window x:Class="VisualBrushMargins.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackground}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="WindowBackground" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid>
                    <Border Background="DarkGreen" Width="250" Height="150" />
                    <Canvas Height="130" Width="180" Background="DarkBlue">
                        <Path>
                            <!-- path goes here -->
                        </Path>
                        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Red" />
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid/>
</Window>
```

[image: what it looks like]

The path fits the canvas. Sizing the canvas and the border differently allows to add a "margin" to the brush -- note how it behaves on window resize. (Canvas is colored blue for illustrational purpose -- actually it's supposed to be transparent)